# Memory Error in multiplying large pandas dataframe with transpose of itself

Tags: python, pandas, covariance, pca

I have a pandas dataframe with 10 rows and 22411 columns. Each row has data corresponding to a particular timepoint. The dataframe is indexed according to timepoints

`time_point = [0, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 24]`.

I want to calculate time averaged co-variance across columns using the following:

```
t = (data - data.mean())/time_point[i]
cor = (t.T.dot(t))/time_point[i]
```

This gives me a memory error.

Also, after calculating the time averaged co-variance, I need to do a PCA on the co-variance. Please suggest some workaround.

I am thinking of storing the co-variance of each column with the others separately (for every column) in pandas HDFStore, then combine them into a dataframe and then do a PCA on it. Am I doing it right?

Comment: This post may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177464/quickest-way-to-calculate-subset-of-correlation-matrix