# pandas get index of highest dot product

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dot-product

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[5,6,7,8],'c':[9,10,11,12]})
    a   b   c
0   1   5   9
1   2   6   10
2   3   7   11
3   4   8   12
```

And I would like to create another column in this dataframe which stores for every row, which other row gets the highest score when performed a dot product against.

For instance for the first row we'll compute the dot products against the other rows:

```
df1.drop(0).dot(df1.loc[0]).idxmax()
output: 3
```

Therefore I can create a function:

```
def get_highest(dataframe):
    lis = []
    for row in dataframe.index:
        temp = dataframe.drop(row).dot(dataframe.loc[row])
        lis.append(temp.idxmax())
    return lis
```

And I get what I want with:

```
df1['highest'] = get_highest(df1)
output: 
    a   b   c   highest
0   1   5   9   3
1   2   6   10  3
2   3   7   11  3
3   4   8   12  2
```

Ok that's working, but the problem is that it doesn't scale AT ALL. Here are the outputs of `timeit` for different number of rows:

```
4 rows: 2.87 ms
40 rows: 77.1 ms
400 rows: 700 ms
4000 rows: 10.4s
```

And I have to perform this on a dataframe which has roughly 240k rows and 3.3k columns. Therefore here is my question: Is there a way to optimize this calculation? (likely by addressing it in another way)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I added the numpy tag because probably a numpy based solution will be faster so numpy folks can also have a look at it.

Comment: @ayhan Good idea, thank you

Comment: This might be helpful.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/38177464/2336654

Answer (score 2):

Do a matrix multiplication with the transpose:

```
mat_mul = np.dot(df.values, df.values.T)
```

Fill diagonals with a small number so they cannot be the maximum (I assumed all positive, so filled with -1 but you can change this):

```
np.fill_diagonal(mat_mul, -1)
```

Now take the argmax of the array:

```
df['highest'] = mat_mul.argmax(axis=1)
```

Timings on a 10k by 4 df:

```
%%timeit
mat_mul = np.dot(df.values, df.values.T)
np.fill_diagonal(mat_mul, -1)
df['highest'] = mat_mul.argmax(axis=1)

1 loop, best of 3: 782 ms per loop

%timeit df['highest'] = get_highest(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 9.8 s per loop
```

Comment: Thank you for your enswer, actually I've already tried that, but the problem is that `np.dot` on big dataframes takes a lot of memory so I instantly get a `MemoryError`. Maybe there is a way to chunk the dataframe? I don't know quite much about chunking.

Comment: Honestly I also don't know how to do matrix multiplication piece by piece efficiently. Let me try a few things.

Answer (score 2):

Since the dot-products would be repeated for pairs when they are flipped, the final dot-product array for each row against every other row would be a symmetric one. So, we can calculate for either the lower or upper triangular dot product elements and then get the full form by using [`scipy's squareform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html). Thus, we would have an implementation like so -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

arr = df1.values
R,C = np.triu_indices(arr.shape[0],1)
df1['highest'] = squareform(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',arr[R],arr[C])).argmax(1)
```

Output for sample case -

```
In [145]: df1
Out[145]: 
   a  b   c  highest
0  1  5   9        3
1  2  6  10        3
2  3  7  11        3
3  4  8  12        2
```

Comment: This is a good idea, it beats my code until 4k rows, but when I try 40k rows, it appears that they match, so I tend to think that it would be that good on my main dataframe unfortunately

Comment: @ysearka Let me ask you - Do you have negative numbers in the dataframe? Also, replace `np.einsum('ij,ij->i',arr[R],arr[C])` with `(arr[R]*arr[C]).sum(1)` and see if still there's mismatch?

Comment: Deeply sorry for the delay, I've been focused on another urgent task. I have no negative number in my dataframe, they are actually quantities (counts or volumes). And trying your replacement sadly doesn't improve computation time.

Comment: @ysearka Is there value mismatch or its just slower or both?

Comment: It yields the same result, but is slightly slower (+2ms for 400 rows for instance, or +100ms for 4000 rows).