# calculating the covariance matrix fast in python with some minor customizing

Tags: pandas, covariance

I have a pandas data frame and I'm trying to find the covariance of the percentage change of each column. For each pair, I want rows with missing values to be dropped, and the percentage be calculated afterwards. That is, I want something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dataframe example
N_ROWS, N_COLS = 249, 3535
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((N_ROWS, N_COLS)))
df.iloc[np.random.choice(N_ROWS, N_COLS), np.random.choice(10, 50)] = np.nan

cov_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.columns, columns=df.columns)
for col_i in df:
    for col_j in df:
        cov = df[[col_i, col_j]].dropna(how='any', axis=0).pct_change().cov()
        cov_df.loc[col_i, col_j] = cov.iloc[0, 1]
```

The thing is this is super slow. The code below gives me results that is similar (but not exactly) what I want, but it runs quite fast

```py
df.dropna(how='any', axis=0).pct_change().cov()
```

I am not sure why the second one runs so much faster. I want to speed up my code in the first, but I can't figure out how.

I have tried using `combinations` from `itertools` to avoid repeating the calculation for `(col_i, col_j)` and `(col_j, col_i)`, and using `map` from `multiprocessing` to do the computations in parallel, but it still hasn't finished running after 90+ mintues.

Comment: It's too late for me to read through properly.  Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52371329/2336654

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38195754/2336654

Comment: Thanks, looking at them now and trying to see how they can help. Probably won't update before Monday though.

Comment: @piRSquared I finished reading the second link and I think it's a bit different. The problem posted in the second link seems to be with memory issue. The data was too big so `df.corr()` was slow. On the other hand, my data frame isn't that big and runs fast enough when I just use `df.corr()`,  but the result isn't what I want. Still checking out the first link

Comment: @piRSquared The first link seems to help. It also involves doing it over a loop. I haven't test it out yet. It uses `numba`, but I wonder if there is a way to do this without numba, since `df.corr()` itself is quite fast, and I feel like my calculation isn't doing something that much different from it.

Answer (score 0):

somehow this works fast enough, although I am not sure why

```py
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

corr = np.zeros((x.shape[1], x.shape[1]))
for i in range(x.shape[1]):
    for j in range (i + 1, x.shape[1]):
        y = x[:, [i, j]]
        y = y[~np.isnan(y).any(axis=1)]
        y = np.diff(y, axis=0) / y[:-1, :]
        if len(y) < 2:
            corr[i, j] = np.nan
            continue
        y = pearsonr(y[:, 0], y[:, 1])[0]
        corr[i, j] = y
corr = corr + corr.T
np.fill_diagonal(corr, 1)
```

This takes within 8 minutes, which is fast enough for my use case.

On the other hand, this has been running for 30 minutes but still isn't done.

```py
corr = pd.DataFrame(index=nav.columns, columns=nav.columns)
for col_i in df:
    for col_j in df:
        corr_ij = df[[col_i, col_j]].dropna(how='any', axis=0).pct_change().corr().iloc[0, 1]
        corr.loc[col_i, col_j] = corr_ij
t1 = time.time()
```

Don't know why this is but anyways the first one is a good enough solution for me now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).